# Struggling with unicode in Python

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to automate the extraction of data from a large number of files, and it works for the most part.  It just falls over when it encounters non-ASCII characters:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position
>   5: ordinal not in range(128)

How do I set my 'brand' to UTF-8?  My code is being repurposed from something else (which was using lxml), and that didn't have any issues.  I've seen lots of discussions about encode / decode, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to implement it.  The below is cut down to just the relevant code - I've removed the rest.

```
i = 0

filenames = [y for x in os.walk("Distributor") for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.xml'))]

for i in range (len(filenames)):
    pathname = filenames[i]

    fin = open(pathname, 'r')
    with codecs.open(('Assets'+'.log'), mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(u'File Path|Brand\n')
        lines = fin.read()
        brand_start = lines.find("Brand Title")
        brand_end = lines.find("/>",brand_start)
        brand = lines [brand_start+47:brand_end-2]
        f.write(u'{}|{}\n'.format(pathname[4:35],brand))

flog.close()
```

I'm sure there is a better way to write the whole thing, but at the moment my focus is just on trying to understand how to get the lines / read functions to work with UTF-8.

Comment: You should show the full error including the traceback. Apart from anything else, that says which line the error occurred in.

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing bytestrings with Unicode values; your `fin` file object produces bytestrings, and you are mixing it with Unicode here:

```
f.write(u'{}|{}\n'.format(pathname[4:35],brand))
```

`brand` is a bytestring, interpolated into a Unicode format string. Either decode `brand` there, or better yet, use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) (rather than `codecs.open()`, which is not as robust as the newer `io` module) to manage *both* your files:

```
with io.open('Assets.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f,\
        io.open(pathname, encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    f.write(u'File Path|Brand\n')
    lines = fin.read()
    brand_start = lines.find(u"Brand Title")
    brand_end = lines.find(u"/>", brand_start)
    brand = lines[brand_start + 47:brand_end - 2]
    f.write(u'{}|{}\n'.format(pathname[4:35], brand))
```

You also appear to be parsing out an XML file by hand; perhaps you want to use the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead to parse out those values. In that case, you'd open the file without `io.open()`, so producing byte strings, so that the XML parser can correctly decode the information to Unicode values for you.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the fundamental problem.  One final issue is that it keeps overwriting the file contents, so I just get two lines of "File Path|Brand" and  "SYNT0000000000001045-20150331T095311Z|Something Here|".  I changed 'w' to 'a' but then the File Path|Brand is repeated on every other line.  Suggestions?

Comment: @Nick: why not create the file *outside* of whatever loop you have then?

Comment: Also, you are correct.  I am already using lxml to pass parts of the xml.  This was supposed to be a quick and dirty solution, as I wasn't sure how to resolve this particular scenario with it (lots of similar children in the structure).  I'll open a separate thread to get that working properly, once I've resolved my immediate need to get the information out of the files.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code, using the guidance from above.  It's not pretty, but it solves the problem.  I'll look at getting it all working using lxml at a later date (as this is something I've encountered before when working with different,  larger xml files):

```
import lxml
import io
import os

from lxml import etree
from glob import glob

nsmap = {'xmlns': 'thisnamespace'}

i = 0

filenames = [y for x in os.walk("Distributor") for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.xml'))] 

with io.open(('Assets.log'),'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(u'File Path|Series|Brand\n')

    for i in range (len(filenames)):
        pathname = filenames[i]
        parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser()
        tree = lxml.etree.parse(pathname, parser)
        root = tree.getroot()
        fin = open(pathname, 'r')

        with io.open(pathname, encoding='utf-8') as fin:  

            for info in root.xpath('//somepath'):
                series_x = info.find ('./somemorepath')
                series = series_x.get('Asset_Name') if series_x != None else 'Missing'
                lines = fin.read()
                brand_start = lines.find(u"sometext")
                brand_end = lines.find(u"/>",brand_start)
                brand = lines [brand_start:brand_end-2]
                brand = brand[(brand.rfind("/"))+1:]
                f.write(u'{}|{}|{}\n'.format(pathname[5:42],series,brand))

f.close()
```

Someone will now come along and do it all in one line!